# Как преходить между страницами на React?

Tags: reactjs

Я как-то не смог седлать переход со страницы на другую

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './navbar'
import Registr from '../pages/registr'
const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="Login">
            <h1 className="title">Вход</h1>
            <form>
                <input className="input" name="E-mail" placeholder="E-mail" /><br/>
                <input className="input" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" /><br/>
                <button className="btn" type="submit">Отправить</button>
            </form>
            <Router>
                <div className="info">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <h5>Если ты еще не снами, то скорей сюда - <br/><Link exact to="/registr"><span id="reg">Регистрация</span></Link></h5>   
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/registr">
                            <Registr />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router> 
        </div>
        <div className="for_users">
            <p>2020 <br/>
            все права защищены 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: У тебя какой-то старый `react-router-dom`... В новом роутинг делается не так. Вот тебе статейка на эту тему - https://ru.hexlet.io/blog/posts/react-router-v6

Answer (score 0):

В ваше примере я не вижу вообще не одного перехода, вот как они реализуются

1: `<Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>`

2:

```
function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Вот простой пример настройки роутинга, попробуйте в нем разобраться https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic